# Microsoft Grapi API SDK Sharepoint LIst

Tags: c#, list, sharepoint

I am just trying to filter a simple test sharepoint list.  Every time I run the code below I get an Invalid filter clause error.  I have tried every combination/syntax I can find.  Any suggestions will be helpful.  When Im done, I would like to be able to filter on modified date.  Basically bringing back all records between two datetime.

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>()
{
  new QueryOption("expand","fields")
 ,new QueryOption("$filter","fields/Field 1 eq 'Field 1 value'")
};
var aa = await graphClient.Sites["{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}"].Lists[sharepointlistid].Items.Request(queryOptions).GetAsync();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my test, the below works for me. Please make sure that you are using the internal name of the field in the filter.

```
        var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>()
            {
                new QueryOption("$expand","fields"),
            new QueryOption("$filter","fields/Title eq 'testValue'")
            };

        var items = await graphClient
            .Sites["{site-id}"]
            .Lists["{list-id}"]
            .Items
            .Request(queryOptions)
            .Header("Prefer", "HonorNonIndexedQueriesWarningMayFailRandomly")
            .GetAsync()
```